# Recompile Arduino Target for Simulink for Windows 64 bit

Tags: matlab, 64-bit, compilation, arduino, simulink

I want to use Arduino Target for Simulink. It is made only for 32bit versions of Windows, but I read that you can recompile it and use it in 64-bit Windows.

I have tried, but I have not succeeded. I think that the files you need to create are the ones ending on `.mexw32`. What do you use to recompile these?

Comment: the file's extension is just a convention, all mex files are dll's. What did you try, and what did not succeed? some info would help (compiler errors etc.) (And by the way, the mexw32 is extension indicating windows 32-bit platform http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html#example1)

Comment: are you sure it does not run on 64-bit Windows? Most 32-bit applications do. I use a 64-bit version of Windows and run a lot of 32-bit applications without any problems.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: 32-bit mex files do not work with a 64-bit Matlab installation, and it's difficult to impossible to install 32-bit Matlab on Win64.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24675-arduino-target:

> To compile the C files for win64 (or
>   another platform), first make sure you
>   have a supported compiler:
>   http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2010b/win64.html
>
> Once you have a compiler installed,
>   you can run "mex -setup" to point to
>   the appropriate compiler.
>
> Finally, you can run "mex filename.c"
>   to compile all the functions in the
>   blocks directory.